# package in sparklauncher in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I do `spark-submit` with `spark-csv`, I use the following command

```
spark-submit --master spark://10.0.0.1:7077 --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0  MyApp.jar
```

(**note**: I'm using `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0`)

The question is: How can I do that with spark launcher (I can't find where to put in the package information from the API)?

(Following is the code I'm using)

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher

object Launcher extends App {

  val spark = new SparkLauncher()
  .setSparkHome("/myspark1.5.1path/")
  .setAppResource("/mypath/MyApp.jar")
  .setMainClass("MyApp")
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .launch()
  spark.waitFor()
}
```

Comment: Apparently you can't (yet). https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html

Comment: You can use maven shade plugin [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265456/how-to-pre-package-external-libraries-when-using-spark-on-a-mesos-cluster/32403191#32403191)

Answer (score 2):

```scala
spark.addSparkArg("--packages", "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0")
```