# Intellij artifact tool doesn't create correct executable spark jar

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I created a Spark maven project in IntelliJ IDEA 2018 and tried to export an executable jar file of my main class. As I try to submit it to Yarn cluster, it errors `The main class not found!` while the `MANIFEST.MF` includes it:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
```

I did the same with other processing engines like Apache Flink and IntelliJ could create an executable jar file that successfully runs on the cluster.

So in Spark case I always have to use `maven-assembly-plugin` and export the jar file using the command:`mvn clean compile assembly:single`

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Test</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I guess it's because of spark dependencies format. I faced the same problem in creating a jar file from my written class using Spark dependencies(not executable). For example, adding `spark-sql` dependency to Maven project eventuate in getting some other dependencies like `spark-catalyst`. Is there any way to export Spark executable jar file using IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score -1):

`maven-shade-plugin` can be alternative option to create Uber jar. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403191/1362926) is the detailed pom.xml.

Comment: As I said un the question, I did it using `maven-shade-plugin`.But I want to know is any way to make jar file using IntellJ!?

Comment: Intellij is editor, not a build tool, you have to use some kind of plugin to achieve. Intellij having very good support for maven. And you don't need Manifest file and a executable jar. What all you need to run your application with spark is that  all classes and its dependency should be in jar.